# Cokernel of a $\mathbb{Z}/p$-vector space map

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to explicitly describe the kernel of a map of $\mathbb{Z}/p$-vector spaces for a prime $p$, and for some reason this puzzles me a lot. For example, if we have a map
$$
\mathbb{Z}/p \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p \to \mathbb{Z}/p \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p
$$
given by
\begin{align*}
(1,0) & \mapsto (1, a) \\
(0,1) & \mapsto (b,1)
\end{align*}
for some $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}/p$, let's assume $a,b \neq 0,1$ and $p$ odd. So the image can be described as $\mathbb{Z}/p(1,a)+ \mathbb{Z}/p(b,1)$. Is there in general as nice way to describe the cokernel of this map? Same question also for the map
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}/p & \to \mathbb{Z}/p \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p \\
(0,1) & \mapsto (1,a)
\end{align*}
I know the dimension of the cokernels etc. but I'm interested in the specific generating elements w.r.t. a basis, say $\{e_1, e_2\}$ of $\mathbb{Z}/p \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p$. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: The cokernel is zero if $1-ab\neq 0\in Z/p$ and $Z/p$ if it is zero in the first question.

Comment: What kind of description would you like? You can find a basis for the image (by row reduction) then extend it with vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$ to a basis for the codomain (by Steinitz exchange--more row reduction). Then a basis for the cokernel is $v_1+\mathop{im}(T), \dots v_k+\mathop{im}(T)$.